# Python splitting but keeping the split string

Tags: python

I find myself doing this pattern a lot:

```
new_url = season_url.split('cid=')[0] + 'cid='
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def truncate_after(s, needle):
    partition_pos = s.index(needle)+len(needle)
    return s[:partition_pos]
```

It could also return the other part if you wanted both pieces.

Comment: Python makes it very easy to define a function. If you find yourself doing something very often, even if it's trivial, just make a function for it. The body of the function doesn't even matter much, the original code from the question would work just as well here.

Answer (score 2):

Try `str.partition()`, which creates a `list` of length 3 consisting of the portion before the split characters, the split characters, and the portion after the split characters:

```
new_url = ''.join(season_url.partition('cid=')[:2])
```